# How do I identify an empty NSData Object that appears as empty brackets?

Tags: ios, nsdata, gamekit, null, gkturnbasedmatch

I am dealing with a corruption issue in Game Kit's GKTurnBasedMatch class (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373903/removing-a-gkturnbasedmatch-which-is-in-an-invalid-state/15725033)) which sometimes results in an invalid game state, with corrupted matchData.

So as a workaround, I'm creating a way out a way to identify these invalid matches so I can deal with them appropriately.  The corrupted matchData seems like a good way to do this.  However, so far I've been unable to identify them.  When I do this:

```
// "match" is an existing GKTurnBasedMatch object
NSLog(@"match data is: %@",[match matchData]);
NSLog(@"match data is nil? %@",[match matchData] == nil ? @"YES" : @"NO");
NSLog(@"match data equals empty nsdata? %@",[match matchData] == [NSData data] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

I get the following:

```
match data is: <>
match data is nil? NO
match data equals empty nsdata? NO
```

So the match data is showing up as a pair of empty brackets "<>", which I would hope could be identified as **nil**, but apparently not.

Incidentally, I am storing this matchData in a core data entity, under an NSData attribute.  And when I save the NSManagedObjectContext, then NSLog the NSManagedObject to see what's in it, the NSData attribute in question *still* shows up as "<>"!

However, if I then create a *new* NSManagedObjectContext, retreive the same NSManagedObject out of it, *then* NSLog its values, the NSData attribute now shows up as **nil**.

So it appears that at some point, core data is "cleansing" the attribute to its poper **nil** value.  My problem is that I actually need to identify this value as being **nil** *before* that point, at the time when I add it to the core data store.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are doing a comparison of object instances in your last case.  Both of those instances could be empty and the result would not be true.

Try this:

```
 NSLog(@"match data equals empty nsdata? %@",[[match matchData] length] == 0 ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: Had the same problem. Perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

`[NSData data]` returns a new `NSData` object, which will never == an existing object.  To check if it is an empty NSData:

```
[[match matchData] isKindOfClass:[NSData class]] && match.length == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

CoreData does not alter the values you set on the `NSManagedObject` instance. You must be setting an empty `NSData` value.

To check if it is an empty data, check its `length` property. It should be 0 when empty.